# gSoap c++ outputs request xml and then does nothing

Tags: c++, xml, gsoap

I'm having a problem with the gSoap c++ library...

I have generated the proxy classes from the wsdl and included them into my project.

It has no problem compiling, but when I execute it, it just outputs the request xml and then does nothing... it doesn't close, it doesn't output anything else and it just keeps running forever ...

I have also tested the soap api using a test soap client which works without any problems...

Here's  the code which is actually almost 1:1 from this [article](http://coab.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/calling-wcf-services-from-a-linux-c-client-using-gsoap/):

```
#include <iostream>

#include "soap/soapBasicHttpBinding_USCORESearchProxy.h"
#include "soap/BasicHttpBinding_USCORESearch.nsmap"


int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

  struct soap soap;

  BasicHttpBinding_USCORESearchProxy service;

  _ns1__FindNewestArticlesResponse response;
  _ns1__FindNewestArticles request;

  int error = service.FindNewestArticles(&request, &response);

  if(error == SOAP_OK){
    std::cout << "ok";
  }else{
    std::cout << "not ok";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Howare you invoking your server?

Comment: Shouldn't request be initialized in any more complicated way?

Comment: @RaulAndres I'm not, it's just a client consuming a remote soap-service. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @vard It's a proxy class generated by gSoap

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger? Where does it hang? Have you tried using a client-side proxy to watch the traffic?